# how to write simultaneous subscript and superscript for a symbol with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to get something like that: $E^{\alpha}_{\beta}$, where there are simutaneous subscript \beta and superscript \alpha for the symbol E.
I type in matplotlib (1.2.x with python 2.7.1) the following code:

```
ax.text(0.,0.,r'E$^{\alpha}_{\beta}$')
```

and I get an error message:

```
Subscript/superscript sequence is too long. Use braces { } to remove ambiguity.
```

When I added extra braces to separate the superscript and subscript like

```
ax.text(0.,0.,r'E${^{\alpha}}_{\beta}$')
```

matplotlib can handle it this time, but the result is not a SIMULTANEOUS superscript and subscript, it seems the symbol E$^{\alpha}$ with a subscript \beta, where \alpha and \beta are not vertically aligned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Move your `E` into the TeX so that the processor knows what `alpha` and `beta` are hanging off of:

```
text(0.25, 0.5, r'$E^{\alpha}_{\beta}$', size=200)
```

produces

[image]